# How do I make a command to refresh itself without writing a .sh script?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm doing that command to measure RAM usage:

`while sleep 1; do free && echo -e && ps -eo rss | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}' && echo -e "\n"; done`

However, it still keeps printing new outputs instead of erasing/overwriting the last one.

The goal is about making that command looks like top or htop behavior.

So the question is: Without writing a shell script, how do I make a command to refresh itself ?

---

I've stumbled upon this: https://askubuntu.com/a/684887

So `printf "\033c"` works, but the problem is it behaving like reset, which clears the whole terminal except the last output.

Besides, `watch` also works, but quitting it won't keep the last output, like top does.

Is there a way to mix both ? Like mimic-ing top's behavior ?

Top refreshes itself, without resetting the whole terminal and keeps the last output when quitting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `watch` command. To run the command you've specified, something like:

```
watch -n 1 'free -t && echo && ps -eo rss | awk '\''{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'\'' && echo'
```

Pay special attention the special quoting around the `awk` command necessary to put single quotes inside single quotes.

`watch` runs the program at a specified interval (1 second here, with the `-n 1` flag) and displays the first screen of output on the screen, refreshing each time.

If you're set on making the output persist after you quit, you can run the command once more at the end. Something like:

```
tmp='free -t && echo && ps -eo rss | awk '\''{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'\'' && echo'
watch -n 1 "$tmp" ; eval "$tmp"
```

Where I'm just using the temporary variable `$tmp` to avoid typing the whole command twice.

Comment: So that's why awk didn't worked with watch when I tried... Besides, "echo -e" seems to behave weird since instead of having a \n, I do get "-e" output.

Comment: By "-e" output, I meant that it literally output "-e" instead of having a blank line.  Also, watch seems to reset itself after being done, while top's output is still there after quitting it; is there a way to mimic that ?

Comment: If you want a blank line, just do `echo` with no arguments: that prints a newline by default. It's acting like that because `watch` calls `/bin/sh`, and `-e` is a bash extension. I've edited my answer to get rid of the superfluous `-e`'s.

Comment: Well, unless I'm missing something, that's probably because of the `&& echo -e &&` on the left-hand side of the pipe. You haven't given it a string to echo, so its probably interpreting the `-e` flag as an argument, rather than an option.

Comment: @tjt263 Nope, it's the different interpretation of `echo` in `/bin/sh` versus `/bin/bash`. The POSIX [echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) doesn't support any options, except possibly `-n`.

Comment: Yup, simply using `echo` did the trick.

Comment: @X.LINK I don't think there's a way to get `watch` to persist. You could run the command once more after `watch` quits if you really want to make sure it stays on the screen, I suppose.

Comment: Oh right. Anyway, `printf` ftw.

Comment: @tjt263 `printf` is definitely the way to go for portability. But `echo` is shorter than `printf '\n'` or `printf \\n` (and also portable, in this case) :p

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't mind clearing everything else in the terminal window, you could add a `clear` after the sleep:

```
while sleep 1; do clear; free -t && echo -e && ps -eo rss | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}' && echo -e "\n"; done
```

Comment: Damn, me always using ctrl-l made me forgot "clear". It does works, but that's a quick and dirty way to do things. I'll take it as a last resort though.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to avoid printing in subcommands (such as `awk`) and get everything in variables instead, and then print everything in one line with a CR instead of a LF at the end (I use bash `printf` for this):

```
 printf "%10s %4d %4d\r" $dev $recvdiff $senddiff
```

Comment: The bad thing is, I can't do that command without awk. Or is there a way to have the total resident RAM usage I'm not aware of ? Also, is there a way to do that with echo since printf is slower in CPU times ?